# Plural use of Necklace

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

Why does the last line in the short story [The Necklace](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Complete_Short_Stories_of_Guy_de_Maupassant/The_Diamond_Necklace#:%7E:text=Oh!%20my%20poor%20Matilda!%20Mine%20were%20false.%20They%20were%20not%20worth%20over%20five-hundred%20francs!) treat *necklace* as plural?

> > *Mine were false. They were not worth over five hundred francs!*

But the [translation](https://en.m.wikisource.org/wiki/Stories_by_Foreign_Authors_(French_I)/The_Necklace#:%7E:text=my%20necklace%20was%20paste.%20It%20was%20worth%20at%20most%20five%20hundred%20francs!) by Jonathan Sturges reads:

> > *...my necklace was paste. It was worth at most five hundred francs!*

Can someone provide some clarification on this?

Comment: “Mine were false” probably refers to the diamonds of the necklace.

Comment: In the original text, it was singular: - Oh! ma pauvre Mathilde! Mais la mienne était fausse. Elle valait au plus cinq cents francs!... http://clicnet.swarthmore.edu/litterature/classique/maupassant/parure.html

Comment: @user66974 Thank you! That makes it clear :)

Comment: Sounds like Sturges did a much better job of translation.